# Find a nonempty set $A$ such that $A\cap P(A)=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- Find a nonempty set $A$ such that $A\cap P(A)=\emptyset$. (as $P(A)$ is power set of$A$).

My solition. Let $A=${$\emptyset, 1$} be set. Then, $P(A)=${$\emptyset$, {$\emptyset$},{$1$},$A$}. Hence, $A\cap P(A)=\emptyset$. **Can you check my solition?**

Comment: In your answer, $A \cap P(A)$ contains $\emptyset$, so in particular that intersection is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a set $A$, none of whose members are subsets of $A$. There's lots of those! The simplest possible example would be a set of one element; can you find one which works?

Another hint: the cardinality of a subset of a finite set is less than or equal to the cardinality of the set. So if $A$ is finite, all its subsets are of cardinality less than or equal to $|A|$. Can you make finite $A$ so that all its members have infinite cardinality, but all its subsets have finite cardinality?

Comment: Did you try using the hint? A finite set whose members all have infinite cardinality will immediately work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $\{\emptyset,1\} \cap \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{1\},A\} = \{\emptyset\}$

Hint: $\emptyset \in p(A)$ for any set $A$. So if $\emptyset \in A$, we can never have $A \cap P(A) = \emptyset$. It's important to distinguish $\emptyset=\{\}$, and $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: What is $\emptyset\in A$ mean?

Comment: @Kahler, this exatcly th important distinction. There is a difference between a box containing a shoe, and the shoe itself, and analogously there is a difference between a box containing a box nothing nothing ($\{\emptyset\}$), and just a box contining nothing ($\emptyset$).